# Why does this Java program cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, linux, javafx, memory-leaks, windows-7

This code causes a memory leak which the NetBeans profiler cannot see. The leak is not that bad on Windows and appears to level out but absolutely kills the memory of a Linux machine when run. If I comment out the setText method on the label the memory is not leaked. If I print out to the console instead of sending the text to the label the leak does not happen.

I think the setText() method is holding onto the old values for some reason.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class Sandbox {


    Label theLabel;
    boolean isUpdating = false;
    int count = 0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sandbox();
    }   

    public Sandbox(){

        new JFXPanel(); // this will prepare JavaFX toolkit and environment
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            }
        });

        theLabel = new Label();
        root.getChildren().add(theLabel);

        while(true){
            try{
                count ++;
                if(isUpdating == false){
                    isUpdating = true;
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            theLabel.setText("TEST:" + count); //The culprit
                            isUpdating = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                Thread.sleep(0);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually leaking memory, rather than just using everything available to it? The JVM doesn't generally clean up garbage unless it has to.

Comment: that infinite loop cant be good...

Comment: @Reimeus: In production this code is ran using an executor service and a runnable that calls itself. I tried to slim down and simplify the program to make the error easier to find.

Comment: @resueman: The Netbeans profiler shows the memory heap staying right around 100MB but the System Monitor shows the memory being used at around 50MB a second.

Comment: Are you using a scheduled executor service, which regularly executes the runnable or do you simply enqueue it once? What is the method that you use to execute the runnable?

Comment: @StefanDollase I'm not seeing how this relates to the memory leak issue. I'll try to explain it as simply as I can:

I use a Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() to create and Executor. I then have a class which implements Runnable (UpdateTask). At the end of UpdateTask I submit the task again if the display is still running. I have a static final reference to the update task.

Comment: I thought, maybe you are running in a fork-bomb like situation by using a scheduled executor service. This would be the case if you use a scheduled executor service AND you constantly submit new tasks from the task itself. This would cause the executor service queue to grow exponentially in size.

Comment: Yea I see, I think the issue is the label isn't getting rid of the old data.

Comment: You can see the source code for JavaFX [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt). Basically, the `Label` class uses a `SimpleStringProperty` to hold the text value. `#setText()` doesn't do anything special--If it leaked, I would guess that all of the JavaFX controls would leak.

Comment: @iboisver that makes sense, I think the memory comes about during render time. If I set the text to the same string each update the memory leak does not happen. I'm going to try updating my graphics card driver to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that JavaFX has an issue with the default Linux driver (Noveau). After I installed the correct graphics driver for my system (NVidia Quatro K2200) the memory leak went away.